# Dual light switch changing to dual smart switch

Tags: electrical, switch, smart-switch

I currently have 2 switches. Each switch has a black wire and a white attached to it. I’m trying to install a dual smart switch, which requires 4 black wires and a neutral wire.  Confused on how to accomplish this with what I have. Can I split the neutral wire into a neutral and two black wires? Is that safe?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Model # of smart switch?

Answer (score 1):

If all you have in the switch box is the black , white and ground this is a switch leg and your new smart switch probably needs a neutral (white wire in the box not connected to the switch)

The wires connected to the switch now are a hot and a switched hot. Many smart switches need a neutral to provide power for the electronics of the switch.

If you have a neutral in the box tie the new switch white to the neutral it should be white or gray. The next steps depends on the color wires on the new switches. But if you only have the one cable in the box with 2-3 wires it cannot be done with your existing wiring without additional wiring.

Comment: There are some smart switches that work without a neutral connection. Checkout the Caseta line.

Comment: I have them and use them but most require a neutral without a model the answer could be accurate.